# exception CommandNotFound - Discord.ext

Tags: python, exception, discord.py

I was asking the last question I asked, and I realized that it did not work, I used two things:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error): 
if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
    await ctx.author.send(erro + ' | No command called `{}`'.format(ctx.command))
    return
 print('1')
```

I had seen this [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.CommandNotFound), but this is passing the code, it is coming in print ('1') that was not what I wanted

Comment: This works for me.  could you double check the indentation here? Are you definitely on the rewrite branch?

Comment: You have a typo, `.send(error +'| `